# bubble tag cloud with distance

Tags: javascript, graph, cloud, bubble-chart

I've seen many many great javascript libraries for data visualization with bubbles..

as great as they may be, they don't fit my need(or perhaps they do)

I am looking for a javascript library for creating bubble graphs with which the size of the bubble means popularity but the location of the bubbles display relation with the other bubbles (assume the relation is manually defined)

so for instance, if I have the bubbles for - `animals,dog,bulldog,chiwawa,dalmatian,golden retriever, cat, persian,siemese,street cat` I would have a bubble for each but the dog types would be around the dog bubble, the cat types would be around the cat bubble, and all bubbles would be around animals bubble.

Now it is possible to implement this with a circular treemap as displayed [here](http://lip.sourceforge.net/ctreemap.html) but that means that each bubble has only one "parent" bubble.
What if another bubble comes as "Things I have that ruin furniture". This has a relation with (for example) persian cat and bulldog.
These 2 specific bubbles should be as close as possible to the new bubble and also to their original "parents"

I hope I made my need clear..
Is there such a library? or is there a different, more recommended way, to visualize such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this library? http://d3js.org/ Try examples from their Gallery
Especially Circle packing http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/pack.html may fit your needs.
GL